# Excel: Determining which argument to MAX() was the maximum

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max

is there a way to check which argument in =MAX(1,3,2) was the maximum? The example should return 2 (or 1 if the index starts at 0).

I have different sources of data and would like to display which one was selected.

thanks!
Bernhard

Comment: are 1,3 and 2 present in cells? or given as input directly in the MAX formula?

Comment: Hi, they are calculated in the MAX() function, like MAX(C37*2,B23*4,D4)

Comment: If they are inside the MAX function, then it would not be possibile. If they are in cells, then there are ways

Comment: is there another function that can do that?

Comment: if the numbers are in same column its possible. But looks like your numbers are in C37, B23 and D4. Quite random. So i guess there is no other way

Comment: @GowthamShiva - Additionally, there isn't a constant calculation; it is different for each. Perhaps a 'helper' group of cells in a contiguous row or column would ease this.

Comment: This would be ultimately possible with nested aggregate functions but your calculations are not constant and there is no predefined order to the cells; in short, it just isn't worth it. Use a 'helper' column or row to put the calculated values into and MATCH on the MAX.

Comment: @Jeeped i agree with you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

`=MATCH(MAX(C37*2,B23*4,D4),CHOOSE({1,2,3},C37*2,B23*4,D4),0)`

If one or more of the three expressions being passed to `MAX` is in reality quite lengthy and/or resource-heavy, it may be worth avoiding its repetition, e.g.:

`=MATCH(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+CHOOSE({1,2,3},C37*2,B23*4,D4))))`

though you should note that the latter is only valid if the results of the three expressions being passed to `MAX` are non-negative.

Regards

Comment: Nice way to fool excel into thinking those calculated values are an array of constants!

Comment: @Jeeped Indeed!